# Returning laravel 5 flash data in view page

Tags: php, laravel-5

I did in controller

```
Session::flash('message', 'Successfully updated!');
```

and in view

```
@if (Session::has('message'))
                            <li>{!! Session::get('message') !!}</li>
                            @endif
```

However, nothing is passed on view, when i do var_dump(Session::get('message')); I can view message, pls help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that in controller... in the method index() before returning the view you might have put that code `Session::flash('message', 'Successfully updated!');`

But the Session class here might be taken from the namespaces used in your controller. So add a `"\"` before session to make it work..

**Like :**

```
\Session::flash('message', 'Successfully updated!');
```

Answer (score 16):

It should be with "\" in your controller:

```
\Session::flash('message', 'Successfully updated!');
```

And in your view use `session()` as in Laravel documentation.

```
@if (Session::has('message'))
    <li>{!! session('message') !!}</li>
@endif
```

Please see the official [Laravel documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/session#flash-data).